# Get a simple boolean value from a GET request using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Well I have a simple form with a dropdown to select one 'product types' of a few. When an item is selected, it'll trigger an `onChange` event. A given product type can have an `expiration date` or not. I want to change the visibility of a field according to it.

I already made a route `/product_type/get_exp/{id}` but I'm having a hard time crafting the jQuery request that'll GET the value and hide the field accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to send a JSON response from that route. Otherwise you're making it yourself harder.

As there's not much code to work with, I'll try to explain it in a generic way...

Create the route (you've already done that). A `get` route is just fine for this.

```
$route->get('product_type/get_exp/{id}', 'Controller@getFooMethod');
```

In the corresponding Controller method, do something like this. Note that I'm typehinting the ProductType model. This will only work however if the model was bound in the router.

```
public function getFooMethod(ProductType $id)
{
    // Check if ID has expiration date field
    // Let's store it in $hasExpiration
    // e.g. $hasExpiration = false

    return Response::json(array('showExpiration'=> (int) $hasExpiration));
}
```

And then in the `onChange` method:

```
$('#SELECT_ID').on('change', function() {
    // Fetch the ID of the selected option.
    var optionID = $(this).attr('data-id'); // please change per your layout definition

    // Construct the url.
    var productTypeExpirationUrl = 'url_to_route_with_trailing_slash/' + optionID;

    // Perform an Ajax GET request using the product type ID.
    $.ajax({
        url: productTypeExpirationUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            // Extract the showExpiration property of result and hide/show the extra field accordingly.
        }
    });
});
```

Please don't forget to send along the CSRF token as well (described [here](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token)), otherwise the request silently fails.

As an additional security measure, I'd hop in some Middleware to only allow Ajax requests on that route.